# "Unsupported serialized class" when using Pyro5 proxy to get object

Tags: python, serialization, pyro

I am updating some code to use Pyro5 (from Pyro3) and can't see how to deal with custom objects that are returned from a method accessed via a Pyro proxy. As a demonstration I have created two simple classes in a file `classes.py`: `Container` has a method that returns an instance of `Item`:

```
from Pyro5.api import expose

class Container:
    @expose
    def get_item(self):
        return Item()

class Item():
    def __str__(self):
        return "item"
```

The `serpent` package can serialize and deserialize objects of type `Item`:-

```
import serpent
from classes import Item

item = Item()
s = serpent.dumps(item)

item2 = serpent.loads(s)
print(item2)
```

Running this prints, as expected:

```
{'__class__': 'Item'}
```

Now I create a Pyro5 daemon and register an instance of `Container`:

```
from Pyro5.api import Daemon
from classes import Container
    
daemon = Daemon(host="localhost", port=5555)
daemon.register(Container(),"container")
daemon.requestLoop()
```

But when I try to obtain an instance of `Item` via the proxy like this

```
from Pyro5.api import Proxy

container = Proxy("PYRO:container@localhost:5555")
print(container.get_item())
```

I get an exception

```
Pyro5.errors.SerializeError: unsupported serialized class: classes.Item
```

If `get_item()` is changed to return a string, all is OK. Is there a way to get my class `Item` to be serialized and deserialized without a lot of extra custom code? Since serpent deals with it OK, and is used by Pyro5, it seems that this should not be too complex!

Comment: Looks like this is because serpent is not able to (de)serialize arbitrary objects containing functions, unlike pickle, which was used in Pyro3. In my serpent example above I am only recovering a dictionary with the class attributes, rather than an actual instance of the class. I guess this is why pickle is avoided due to the arbitrary code execution it could enable. Looks like I need to write some custom (de)serialization code or refactor the application to use a dictionary instead of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question now that I have figured it out, in case someone else has the same problem in future.

Pyro3 (and I think earlier releases of Pyro4) used Pickle to serialize and deserialize objects, and this was able to recreate a wide range of custom objects, including the functions they contained. This can lead to security issues because Pickle will execute arbitrary code when deserializing an object from a potentially untrustworthy source, so late releases of Pyro4 use Serpent instead, and Pickle is not available at all in Pyro5.

In my original example, Serpent is not reconstructing an `Item` object but just a dictionary containing the fields of the object. Pyro tries to convert this dictionary into an `Item` object but doesn't know how, hence "unsupported serialized class".

The recommended approach (https://pyro5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clientcode.html#serialization) is to use builtin types rather than custom classes. Alternatively it is possible to provide the Pyro proxy with a function to convert a dictionary back into the required object. In my artifiical example where the object has no instance state, this is very simple:

```
from Pyro5.api import Proxy, register_dict_to_class
from classes import Item

def item_dict_to_class(classname, d):
    return Item()
register_dict_to_class("classes.Item", item_dict_to_class)

container = Proxy("PYRO:container@localhost:5555")
print(container.get_item())
```